# parse.com calling .save() causes all queries to stop working Android

Tags: android, database, android-asynctask, parse-platform

I have two objects, a establishment object that belongs to a deal object that can be voted upon.  If I up/down vote the same deal multiple times, the seventh time I vote the query just sits and does not do anything.  The app does not crash, but it also does not save.  If I go into another activity that requires a parse.com query that query also will not work.  Here is my up vote logic (down voting is identical).
Assume all vars used are initialized before onCreate().
Are my queries getting backed up in a pipe somewhere?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        upVoteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deal_up_vote_button);
        upVoteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                new UpVoteTask().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    // visually changes buttons if they are selected
    private void setButtons(Boolean queryDb) {

        if (queryDb == true) {
            queryParse();
        }

        // if deal found correctly 
        if (deal != null) {
            // if user found correctly
            if (dealVoteUser != null) {
                if (dealVoteUser.get("vote").toString().equals("0")) {
                    upVoteButton.setPressed(false);
                    downVoteButton.setPressed(true);
                } else if (dealVoteUser.get("vote").toString().equals("1")) {
                    upVoteButton.setPressed(true);
                    downVoteButton.setPressed(false);
                } else if (dealVoteUser.get("vote").toString().equals("2")) {
                    upVoteButton.setPressed(false);
                    downVoteButton.setPressed(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // queries parse and populates vars
    private void queryParse(){
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryDeal = ParseQuery.getQuery("Deal");
        queryDeal.whereEqualTo("objectId", deal_id);
        try {
            deal = queryDeal.getFirst();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryDealVoteUser = ParseQuery
                .getQuery("deal_vote_users");
        queryDealVoteUser.whereEqualTo("deal", deal).whereEqualTo("user",
                ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        try {
            dealVoteUser = queryDealVoteUser.getFirst();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // UpVoteTask AsyncTask
    private class UpVoteTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            if(upVoteProgressDialog != null){
                upVoteProgressDialog.dismiss();
                upVoteProgressDialog = null;
            }
            upVoteProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DealsDetailsActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog message
            upVoteProgressDialog.setMessage("Saving...");
            upVoteProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            upVoteProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            queryParse();

            // if deal found correctly
            if (deal != null) {
                    // if user has not voted yet
                    if (dealVoteUser == null) {
                        // create new and assign vote to 1
                        dealVoteUser = new ParseObject("deal_vote_users");
                        dealVoteUser.put("deal", deal);
                        dealVoteUser.put("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                        dealVoteUser.put("vote", 1);
                        up_votes = deal.getInt("up_votes") + 1;
                        down_votes = deal.getInt("down_votes");
                    // if user already down voted
                    } else if (dealVoteUser.get("vote").toString().equals("0")) {
                        // change vote to 1
                        dealVoteUser.put("vote", 1);
                        up_votes = deal.getInt("up_votes") + 1;
                        down_votes = deal.getInt("down_votes") - 1;
                    // if user already up voted 
                    } else if (dealVoteUser.get("vote").toString().equals("1")) {
                        // already voted up, remove vote
                        dealVoteUser.put("vote", 2);
                        up_votes = deal.getInt("up_votes") - 1;
                        down_votes = deal.getInt("down_votes");
                    // if user already voted but cleared vote
                    } else if (dealVoteUser.get("vote").toString().equals("2")) {
                        // change vote to 1
                        dealVoteUser.put("vote", 1);
                        up_votes = deal.getInt("up_votes") + 1;
                        down_votes = deal.getInt("down_votes");
                    }

                    // calculate overall rating percentage
                    if ((up_votes + down_votes) != 0) {
                        rating = (up_votes / (up_votes + down_votes)) * 100;
                    } else if ((up_votes == 0) && (down_votes == 0)) {
                        rating = 0;
                    } else {
                        rating = 50;
                    }

                    deal.put("rating", rating);
                    deal.put("up_votes", up_votes);

                    try {
                        deal.save();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        dealVoteUser.save();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    // deal not found problem
                }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // visually change buttons without querying db
            setButtons(false);

            //remove progress dialogue
            if(upVoteProgressDialog != null){
                upVoteProgressDialog.dismiss();
                upVoteProgressDialog = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should really use `saveInBackground` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched all parse calls over to ._____InBackground() and I moved the save logic to onPause().  This way I am not making multiple save calls to parse if the user decides to change their vote multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `saveInBackground` method - it will do the same as `save`, but also save it to your application's cache so that you won't get different values while the data is being saved, so it won't have any apparent effect on your application. It's the best method to save or find (it has a 'sister' method named `findInBackground`). It acts like an Async task and does not clog your main thread.

Comment: I switched everything over to .saveInBackground() and .findInBackGround().  This solved my saving problem, but not my query response problem.  

If I vote, undo my vote, and re-vote, when I try and make a list query it never hits the done section.  It just sits there.  Is there a command to kill all current queries to parse?  The only thing I can think of is that making multiple votes creates some kind of jam and my list query is waiting for the other vote saves to finish?